# SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I always seem to get the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token u when i run my code, i have looked through other answers but none have helped me.
I'm using angularjs and passing in the id from a json array.

```
var fav=[];
if($window.localStorage['fav']){
    $scope.fav = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);
} else {
    $scope.fav = [];
};

$scope.togglefav = function(id) {
var a = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);
  if (a.indexOf(id) == -1){
    fav.push(id);
    console.log(fav);
    $window.localStorage['fav'] = JSON.stringify(fav);
    }
    else{
      a.splice(id, 1);
      $window.localStorage['fav'] = JSON.stringify(a);
      console.log(a);
    }
};
```

My current localstorage is empty but the if statement at the should resolve any issue by creating a new array if one isn't  available.

Comment: That error doesn't seem to apply to this code snippet. Have you followed the error to its source in your developer console?

Comment: `JSON.parse(value)` returns this error, if `value` is `undefinied`, check your data - check this Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nzevfvgg/

Comment: I think you may want to replace `var a = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);` with `var a = JSON.parse($scope.fav);` because you seem to be doing the null check in the previous step and saving it to the fav array. Just a guess...

Answer (score 3):

You get that error when you try to parse `undefined`. It parses it as a string, hits the `u` as the first character, which isn't valid JSON format, and throws up. Check the line number on the error to see which is failing, it's likely

```
var a = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);
```

since you don't check if the value exists or not there.

Comment: The error i get says its in the ionic.bundle.js so it doesnt really help me to find which line the problem is on.